# Change json array format for highcharts

Tags: javascript, java, json, highcharts

I am using JSONArray and JSONObject in a @RestController class in Java to generate a json array for highcharts.

The output is in this format: `[{"17":183},{"16":185},{"15":178},{"14":241},{"13":326},{"12":193},{"11":175},{"10":132},{"9":42},{"4":12},{"3":306},{"2":362},{"1":382},{"0":305}]`

I need to change it to this format: `[[1,12],[2,5],[3,18],[4,13],[5,7],[6,4],[7,9],[8,10],[9,15],[10,22],[11,23],[12,13],[13,14],[14,23]]`

Is this doable using JSONArray and JSONObject? or what other solutions do I have?

Comment: you can use the `replace()` method of the `String` class ?

Comment: I don't prefer using this manual way

Comment: Use replace before sending the response `(((yourJsonArrey.toString().replace("{","[")).replace("}","]")).replace("\"","")).replace(":",",")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use inner arrays instead of objects. For example:

```
JsonArray result = Json.createArrayBuilder()
                       .add(Json.createArrayBuilder().add(1).add(12))
                       .add(Json.createArrayBuilder().add(2).add(5))
                       .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the **other** solution, you can parse that data in JS:

```
var parsedData = [];
$.each(json_data, function (key, val) {
  parsedData.push([parseInt(key, 10), val]);
});
```

And data must be sorted ascending by x-values, so it may be necessary to sort data manually too:

```
parsedData.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a[0] - b[0];
});
```